# LINQ to SQL Expression "Orderby" help

Tags: c#, .net, sql, linq

I current have a LINQ expression, although I would like to know it its possible to use the "orderby" directive in conjunction with a specific field in this case "CDGenre" e.g.

```
DataClassesDataContext db = new DataClassesDataContext (); {
from p in db.ArtistName
**orderby p.CDGenre** accending;
select p.CDTitle;
}
```

Will this statement achieve this?

Comment: Have you attempted it? Is there an error message you get when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax looks right to me, there's also the option of:

```
(from p in db.ArtistName
select p.CDTitle).OrderBy(p => p.CDGenre);
```

**edit**: you could select into an object if you want multiple things in the select statement:

```
(from p in db.ArtistName
select new CDObject(p.CDTitle,p.CDGenre,p.CDArtist)).OrderBy(p => p.CDGenre);
```

Comment: @Brett Thanks, although how could I select multiple outputs e.g. select p.CDTitle,p.CDGenre,p.CDArtist; ??

Comment: @Brett Can you explain what (p => p.CDGenre); does please

Comment: I assume it means that p output is euqal to p.CDGenre, but the order by does not state whether its accedning or decdending

Comment: @James - That's a lambda expression, so `p` grabs the object, and then you can select the members of that object, such as `p.CDGenre` like any other object. Just so you don't get confused, the orderby clause could be `.OrderBy(c => c.CDGenre)`, the `p` is not a necessary letter

Comment: @James - there is `.OrderBy()` and `.OrderByDescending()`

Comment: @Brett Thanks you so much, I feel a lot more confident with them now!

Comment: @James - There are two ways to write all linq queries, the format that you wrote above, and from the lambda expression extensions, like `.OrderBy()`, both are acceptable

Answer (score 3):

It's "ascending" not "accending". Maybe that was the problem (and the semicolon in the end):

```
from p in db.ArtistName
orderby p.CDGenre ascending
select p.CDTitle;
```

Comment: Sorry, the code was only theory, I just wanted to make sure theory was possible

Answer (score 0):

From [101 Linq Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#OrderBySimple1):

```
public void Linq29()
{
    string[] words = { "cherry", "apple", "blueberry" };

    var sortedWords =
        from w in words
        orderby w.Length
        select w;

    Console.WriteLine("The sorted list of words (by length):");
    foreach (var w in sortedWords)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(w);
    }
}
```

Your code snippet looks almost right, but won't compile:

```
from p in db.ArtistName
orderby p.CDGenre ascending
select p.CDTitle;
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

Your main idea was already correct, though the default sort order is already ascending, so no extras are required.

```
from p in db.ArtistName
orderby p.CDGenre
select p.CDTitle;
```

For descending order, use

```
from p in db.ArtistName
orderby p.CDGenre descending
select p.CDTitle;
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I have not tried it out, this is the correct way according to this great page of samples:

[LINQ samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746)

[orderby sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336756#OrderByDescendingSimple1)